# list("String") creates ["S","t","r","i","n","g"] instead of ["String"]

Tags: python, string, list

I am new in python. str.split() function is used to split string, But what logic behind list("string") for split string

```
 >>> list("String")
['S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

Why does not it create list of one string like this `['String']`

Comment: Strings are sequences. When you pass `list()` a sequence, it creates one entry per.

Comment: ...see https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/typesseq.html -- you'll see that strings are under "sequence types". Or, in newer docs, https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange

Comment: It is defined to do so.

Comment: The devil does it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list` takes an iterable argument, and produces a list with one element per value from the iterable. A `str` is iterable consisting of each character of the string as a separate element. Note that you can't write `list(1)` to get the list `[1]`, either, because `1` is not iterable.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, `list()` will take any iterable and try to convert it to a list. Since a string is iterable (under the hood, it's really just an array of characters), the `list()` command converts each character to an item.

To create a list where the first item is `'String'` you need to either use list shorthand:

```
my_list = ['String']
```

Or wrap the string in another iterable when passing to `list()`, which feels pretty redundant

```
my_list = list(['String'])
```

Answer (score 0):

list() converts the iterable string into a list which is composed of each element found.

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#list

> The constructor builds a list whose items are the same and in the same order as iterable’s items. iterable may be either a sequence, a container that supports iteration, or an iterator object. If iterable is already a list, a copy is made and returned, similar to iterable[:]. For example, list('abc') returns ['a', 'b', 'c'] and list( (1, 2, 3) ) returns [1, 2, 3]. If no argument is given, the constructor creates a new empty list, [].

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

`list(["string"])
['string']`

It looks like when you use `list("String")` you are sending the text as elements to create the list, not as a full string.

Answer (score 0):

`list()` iterates through the string appending each item to the the list. if you wanted to create a list with the single element `'string'` you could do something like

```
x = list()
to_add = 'string'
x.append(to_add)
print(x)
```

This will create a list that looks like `['string']`

Answer (score 0):

list("strings") will make your variable iterable

if you want to display your variable as ["strings"]

your list should be declared like this

```
list=["strings"]
>>>>>>>>>> list[0] ### should display
>>>>>>>>>> "strings"
>>>>>>>>>> list  ### if it's lenght is equal to 1
>>>>>>>>>> ["strings"] ##### this should be the result
```